# Plot in Mathematica

Tags: plotting

I got a plot ,

```
Pro3=E^(-8 - 4 Sqrt[2] x - x^2)/(
 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) + E^(-8 + 4 Sqrt[2] x - x^2)/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]])
```

[image: s]

Is there a way for it to look like
[image: s]
I don't know much about plotting in Mathematica.

Comment: Try adding `AspectRatio->1/4, Plot Range->{0,0.5}` to options. You can adjust as desired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Pro3=E^(-8 - 4 Sqrt[2] x - x^2)/(
 2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]) + E^(-8 + 4 Sqrt[2] x - x^2)/(2 Sqrt[\[Pi]]);
Plot[
 Pro3,{x,-5,5},
 PlotRange->{Automatic,{0,0.55}},
 PlotStyle->Black,LabelStyle->Black,
 Ticks->{Automatic,{{0.25,"",{0.01,0.01}},{0.5,0.5,{0.01,0.01}}}},
 AspectRatio->0.3
]
```

[image]

Comment: It’s working and thanks